# How can I choose which account is the selected account when sending coins?

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity, truffle, ganache

I am using `truffle console` to interactive smart contract deployed on `Ganache` network. And use below code to send coin to other accounts:

```
truffle(development)> let instance = await MetaCoin.deployed()
truffle(development)> let accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts()

instance.sendCoin(accounts[1], 500)
```

after doing that, I see the transaction happens from `account[0]` to `account[1]`. What I don't understand is why it chooses `account[0]` as the source. Is it a default behaviour? How can I select a different account?

The contract code is:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity >=0.4.25 <0.7.0;

import "./ConvertLib.sol";

// This is just a simple example of a coin-like contract.
// It is not standards compatible and cannot be expected to talk to other
// coin/token contracts. If you want to create a standards-compliant
// token, see: https://github.com/ConsenSys/Tokens. Cheers!

contract MetaCoin {
    mapping (address => uint) balances;

    event Transfer(address indexed _from, address indexed _to, uint256 _value);

    constructor() public {
        balances[tx.origin] = 10000;
    }

    function sendCoin(address receiver, uint amount) public returns(bool sufficient) {
        if (balances[msg.sender] < amount) return false;
        balances[msg.sender] -= amount;
        balances[receiver] += amount;
        emit Transfer(msg.sender, receiver, amount);
        return true;
    }

    function getBalanceInEth(address addr) public view returns(uint){
        return ConvertLib.convert(getBalance(addr),2);
    }

    function getBalance(address addr) public view returns(uint) {
        return balances[addr];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is default behaviour. By default transaction is sent by accounts[0] and since Sendcoin() function uses msg.sender *( msg.sender: A global variable in solidity that is always equal to the account that sent the transaction)* as sender and account passed in parameter as receiver therefore you see the coins being deducted from account[0] and sent to account[0]

To change this use below code to pass optionals to change the account sending transaction
`instance.sendCoin(accounts[1], 10, {from: accounts[2]})`